# 2 divs centered with multiple content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am consuming myself to find a way to solve this...
So, I have 2 content (**CONTENT A** and **CONTENT B**), floated side by side. I am searching for a way to center al of this content, but the problem is that **CONTENT B** has a dynamic width, so I am not figuring out how can I do this...

This is my **[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SRH5a/1/)**.

And here's my **CSS** and **HTML**.

**CSS**

```
.lean-slider-slide {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s;
    -moz-transition: all .7s;
    -ms-transition: all .7s;
    -o-transition: all .7s;
    transition: all .7s;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
.lean-slider-slide.current {
    transition: all .9s;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #00ACDE
}
.pglp span {
    float: left;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family:"museo300";
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #111;
}
div.pglp {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pglp"><span>HELLO: </span>

    <div id="text_slider">
        <div class="text_slide1">
            <p>BANANA</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text_slide2">
            <p>MORANGO</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text_slide3">
            <p>Design Gráfico</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text_slide4">
            <p>NUTELA</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text_slide5">
            <p>PINEAPPLE</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by" center all of this content"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By use of **display:inline_block**;  and removing **float: ...** I got it to the point everything is in the center. BUT, because your 2nd block of information varies in with, the HELLO: will move along... so if this is not realy what you want, point it out, and I would surely try a second time.

Changed the SPAN into a DIV and added a class

```
 <div class="pglp2">HELLO: </div>
```

and edited your css

```
.lean-slider-slide {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s;
    -moz-transition: all .7s;
    -ms-transition: all .7s;
    -o-transition: all .7s;
    transition: all .7s;
    text-align: left;
}
.lean-slider-slide.current {
    transition: all .9s;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #00ACDE 
}
.pglp2 {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family:"museo300";
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #111;
}
div.pglp {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#text_slider {
   display: inline-block;   
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/zuSke/

Comment: The reason for choose to add a `span` is to change style of my `HELLO`, and it works. Thanks man! :)